# Replace the image of a product with its video in the shop page

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, jquery

I am trying to replace the image of the products with its video in the shop page.
I tried this one

```
add_action( 'init', 'get_product_video_url' );

function get_product_video_url() {

   $product_ids = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'fields' => 'ids'
   ) );
   foreach ( $product_ids as $product_id ) {
    $video_url = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'video_url', true );
    
    echo '<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>';
    echo '<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>';
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $(\"<video playsinline=\"playsinline\" autoplay=\"autoplay\" loop=\"loop\" muted=\"muted\" preload=\"metadata\"><source src=\"'$video_url'" type=\"video/mp4\"></video>\").insertAfter(\"ul.products li.product .product-thumbnail .woocommerce-loop-product__link\"); });
    </script>";

   }
 }
```

but I can't get it to work.

Update:

I replaced the jquery with just the woocommerce hook

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'get_product_video_url' );

 function get_product_video_url() {

   $product_ids = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'fields' => 'ids'
   ) );
   foreach ( $product_ids as $product_id ) {
    $video_url = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'video_url', true );
    
   }
   echo "<video playsinline='playsinline' autoplay='autoplay' muted='muted' loop='loop'><source src='$video_url'></video>";
}
```

but now how do I get the video url corresponding with the product.

Comment: Adding an instance of jQuery and jQuery UI for each product is not a good idea. Have a look at [how to properly add jQuery to WordPress](https://wpmudev.com/blog/adding-jquery-scripts-wordpress/) for a start.

Comment: Yes, I know, but how do I pass the $video_url to the separate js file?

Comment: If you've properly [enqueued your script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/), you can use [`wp_localize_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) to pass PHP variables to your Javascript.

Comment: thank you sir. I've updated my question, do you have idea on how to match the video url to the product.